# Spring cloud contract Stub runner wire mock request was not matched'

Tags: spring-boot, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I'm working with Spring Cloud Contract, and I have an endpoint in a stub generated through Spring Cloud Contract. This endpoint takes a path variable '/files/123456' and returns a byte array. However, when the client calls the stub, I receive a 'request was not matched' error."

wiremock file generated :

```js
{
  "id" : "45ddbb71-ceed-47a5-8e30-34df6aa17a3f",
  "request" : {
    "urlPath" : "/files/123456",
    "method" : "GET",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : {
        "equalTo" : "application/octet-stream"
      }
    }
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "base64Body" : "ABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUU ==== dummy base64",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/octet-stream"
    },
    "transformers" : [ "response-sssss", "spring-cloud-contract" ]
  },
  "uuid" : "45ddbb71-ceed-47a5-8e30-34df6aa17a3f",
  "scenarioName" : "Scenario_e2e-upload-download-file",
  "requiredScenarioState" : "Step2",
  "newScenarioState" : "Step3"
}
```

wiremock error :

[image]